# office365 API - Adal.js - Redirect open new window

Tags: javascript, office365, adal.js

I'am using the adal.js office365 authentication library to get an authentication token. 
So I get the token, but it returns in a new window instead of the same.

Is there any property I can set for this or anything else I could have forgotten?

I think there is nothing special with my code..

```
authContext = new AuthenticationContext({
        instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
        tenant: m_Config.SharePoint.Integration.Tenant,
        clientId: m_Config.SharePoint.Integration.ClientID,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
    });

    authContext.handleWindowCallback();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround , you could redirect the current location to the previous saved required page, which is still on the new page, but not original one.
Please refer to this issue: [login redirect is not keeping the started page for non-angular usage](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/80) . And try to modify your code as :

```
// Check For & Handle Redirect From AAD After Login
var isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
authContext.handleWindowCallback();
if (isCallback && !authContext.getLoginError()) {
   window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
}
```

Hope it helps.